# Assembling error in IDA Pro 6.1

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I need to modify a DLL.
I need to patch

```
cmp     byte_1075A02C, 0
```

To

```
mov     byte_1075A02C, 1
```

I tried to use the Patch->Assemble command in IDA Pro, and i have a "Invalid Operand" message.

Anyone have any idea why a have this message please ?

The `cmp     byte_1075A02C, 0`  is equal to : `80 3D 2C A0 75 10 00`
But what is the  `mov     byte_1075A02C, 1` equivalent ?

Tanks a lot for your helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be

```
C6 05 2C A0 75 10 01
```

Answer (score 1):

For a quick general solution, you could always try an online assembler [such as this one](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm).  The syntax for this instruction is `mov byte ptr [0x1075A02C], 1`.  Try it!

Different x86 assemblers use slightly different syntax, so I recommend familiarizing yourself with one and sticking to it.

Comment: I used `objdump -D -b binary -m i386 -Mintel,x86-64 <my_file>` to get results similar to that website which you linked to.